# некликабельные ссылки доб

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование, asp

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему когда напрямую пишу ссылку, то можно кликать на нее и переходить по ней, а если как в коде, приложенном далее, то не нельзя, даже указатель не pointer

```
function IsAuth() {
        if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)userid\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") > 0) {
            jQuery.get("/User/IsAuth", function (resp) {
                let tmp = "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Download\">DOWNLOAD</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Donate\">DONATE</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Edit\">" + resp + "</a></li>";
                jQuery("#menu").html(tmp);
            });
        }
        else {
            let tmp = "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Download\">DOWNLOAD</a></li>" +
                "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Donate\">DONATE</a></li>" +
                "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"LogIn\">LOG IN</a></li>" +
                "<li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Reg\">REGISTRATION</a></li>";
            jQuery("#menu").html(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы был указатель POINTER - у ссылки должен быть атрибут HREF, либо принудительно надо прописывать в CSS `{cursor:pointer}`

В данном коде я не вижу, чтобы у тегов A были ссылки (href).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но суть вопроса не в указателе. если напрямую написать в body <li><a asp-area=\"\" asp-controller=\"User\" asp-action=\"Donate\">DONATE</a></li>, то все работает, а через jquery когда добавляю, то не  работает

Comment: А ранее обработчик CLICK не где не вешался и какая версия jQ? У jQ раньше было что обработчики вешались при загрузки страницы, после появления новых элементов - они не обрабатывались. Для это было придумано событие LIVE(). И только много позже придумали событие ON(), которое уже убирало проблему эту.

Comment: решилось, ответ написал, как можно будет отметить как решение, отмечу, если не забуду, спасибо за внимание, извините за такие глупости...

Answer (score 0):

все, понял, `<a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Donate">DONATE</a>` преобразуется в `<a href="/User/Donate">DONATE</a>`, поэтому и не работало